# getOutputStream() has already been called spring boot

Tags: json, spring-boot, jackson, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to do a query in a many to many relationship. The result is a large Json that makes no sense for me and an error in the spring console.

I don't know why this is happening. I was guided by tutorials to do the many to many relationship.

This is the repository

```
public interface ProductJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {
    @Query(value = "select p from Product p where p.productoId = ?1")
    Product findByProductId(Long productId);    

    List<Customer> findBycustomerId(Long customerId); 
}
```

This is the product

```
...

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="PRODUCTO_ID")
private long productoId;
private String name;
private Long price;
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "products")
private Set<Customer> customers = new HashSet<>();

...
```

This the Customer

```
...

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long customerId;
private String name;
private String email;

@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(
    name= "PRODUCTS_BY_CUSTOMER",
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER_CUSTOMER_ID")},
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_PRODUCTO_ID")}
) 
Set<Product> products = new HashSet<>();

...
```

This is the controller

```
...

@GetMapping(value = "productsList/{productId}")
public Product findByProductId(@PathVariable final Long productId){
    return productJpaRepository.findByProductId(productId); 
}

...
```

and this is the result when I put in the browser http://localhost:8180/products/productsList/3. 
This result extends much more, I only attach a part but the rest is the same

```
{
  "productoId":3,
  "name":"Producto C",
  "price":4000,
  "customers": [
    {
      "customerId":1,
      "name":"Carlos Rodriguez",
      "email":"carlosr@beitch.com",
      "products":[
        {
          "productoId":3,
          "name":"Producto C",
          "price":4000,
          "customers":[
            {
              "customerId":1,
              "name":"Carlos Rodriguez",
              "email":"carlosr@beitch.com",
              "products":[
                {
                  "productoId":3,
                  "name":"Producto C",
                  "price":4000,
                  "customers":[
                    {
                    "customerId":1,
                    "name":"Carlos Rodriguez",
                    "email":"carlosr@beitch.com"
                    ....
```

And finally this is the error in the console

```
2017-10-29 20:17:05.458 ERROR 1640 --- [nio-8180-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:524) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:389) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:254) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:175) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:625) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:211) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:109) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView.render(ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.java:227) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1286) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1041) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a composition of `Customer` in your `Product` entity and vice versa.

You are getting this error because of the un-ending serialization that is going while converting your entity `Product` to `JSON`.

Try either

- `JsonIgnore` on `customers` in the `Product` entity.
- Instead of serializing the complete `Product` object, create a DTO class `ProductDto` that contains only the fields you want at the client side.

  ```
  @GetMapping(value = "productsList/{productId}")
  public ProductDto findByProductId(@PathVariable final Long productId){
      Product product = productJpaRepository.findByProductId(productId); 
      ... 
      //get required properties from product and set in the ProductDto object
      return productDto;
  }
  ```

Comment: Hi @Abdullah Khan, can you tell me why I must put JsonIgnore ? In the examples that i saw in internet, they never mention the JsonIgnore and the program runs ok. I tried with the jasonIgnore and the error has disappeared

Comment: Because as mentioned the main problem is because of the fact that you have circular dependencies in your objects. By using JsonIgnore in the Product entity you dont even include the customers entity hence the error disappears. Please accept and upvote the answer if it has helped you in nay way. Thanks