# JWT+Cookie: 500 Could not write JSON: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response]

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, cookies, jwt

I am fairly new to SpringBoot and ReactJS. Please bear with my ignorance.

I expected that when I sent login request with post method to localhost:8080/collaborator/login, I would get a jwtToken stored in Cookie.
But : with Postman, I got 2 JWT tokens from routes: `localhost:8080/collaborator/` and `localhost:8080/collaborator/login` with Error code "500 Could not write JSON: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response]" on my IntelliJ console.
with ReactJS, I got AxiosError.

I've looked at the two posts:[getOutputStream() has already been called spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007066/getoutputstream-has-already-been-called-spring-boot) and [getOutputStream() has already been called spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007066/getoutputstream-has-already-been-called-spring-boot)

So I supposedly may have : 1. generated JWT tokens twice in a single resquest(why is that illegal?), but I am not able to locate where I generated the second JWT token.

This is the Java code for login:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("collaborator")
public class UserController {
    private UserService userService;
    private JwtGeneratorInterface jwtGenerator;
    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService, JwtGeneratorInterface jwtGenerator){
        this.userService=userService;
        this.jwtGenerator=jwtGenerator;
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<?> loginUser(@RequestBody @NotNull User user, HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
            if(user.getUserName() == null || user.getPassword() == null) {
                throw new UserNotFoundException("UserName or Password is Empty");
            }
            User userData = userService.getUserByNameAndPassword(user.getUserName(), user.getPassword());

            if(userData == null){
                throw new UserNotFoundException("UserName or Password is Invalid");
            }

            // Add jwtToken as a cookie in the response
            Cookie cookie = new Cookie("jwtToken", jwtGenerator.generateToken(user).get("jwtToken"));
            cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
            cookie.setMaxAge(3600); //an hour
            cookie.setPath("/collaborator/login");
            response.addCookie(cookie);

            return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);

        } catch (UserNotFoundException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }
    }
```

2. Postman verified that yes, I received two JWT tokens in cookies upon a post request to http://localhost:8080/collaborator/login. But I didn't set the cookie+JWT  for the path:http://localhost:8080/collaborator/ and I still received a JWT from this path. Why is it so? If there is more information needed, please let me know.
3. The error code I got from Postman is 500, but the error code I got when using npm start is 409, which says AxiosError. I suspect it comes from my distrous code here:

AuthContext.js

```
const AuthContext = createContext();

//this paragraph is cheesy
export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(() => {
    const jwtCookie = document.cookie
        .split("; ")
        .find((cookie) => cookie.startsWith("jwt")); //in Java, I use "jwtToken"
  
    if (jwtCookie) {
        const jwt = jwtCookie.split("=")[1];
        return jwt_decode(jwt);
      }
      return null;
    });


//CONFUSION
//wait, is it reasonable to send cookie using "post" back to server? 
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const login = async (payload) => {
      const apiResponse = await axios.post(
        "http://localhost:8080/collaborator/login",payload
    );

    // Set the JWT token in a cookie instead of local storage
    document.cookie = `jwt=${apiResponse.data.access_token}`;
    setUser(jwt_decode(apiResponse.data.access_token));
    navigate("/");
    };

    const logout = async () => {
    // Remove the JWT token from the cookie, the cookie is expired because the date is past.
    document.cookie = "jwtToken=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;";
  
    setUser(null);
    navigate("/");
    };


  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, login, logout }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Login.jsx

```
import { useContext, useRef } from "react";
import { Col, Container, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import AuthContext from "../components/shared/AuthContext";

const Login = () => {
  const userName = useRef("");
  const password = useRef("");
  const {login}= useContext(AuthContext);

  //I think this is where it goes wrong. 
  const loginSubmit = async () => {
    let payload = {
      username: userName.current.value,
      password: password.current.value
    }
    await login(payload);
  };
```

jwtInterceptor.js

```
import axios from "axios";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";

const jwtInterceptor = axios.create({});

jwtInterceptor.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  let jwtToken = Cookies.get("jwtToken");
  config.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${jwtToken}`;
  return config;
});

jwtInterceptor.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    return response;
  },
  async (error) => {
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
      const jwtToken = Cookies.get("jwtToken");
      const payload = {
        access_token: jwtToken,
        refresh_token: "", // Assuming no refresh token in cookies
      };

      let apiResponse = await axios.post(
        "http://localhost:8080/collaborator/login",payload
      );

      Cookies.set("jwtToken", apiResponse.data.access_token);
      error.config.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${apiResponse.data.access_token}`;
      return axios(error.config);
    } else {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  }
);

export default jwtInterceptor;
```

Comment: Please try to isolate your problem, you have an error from Sring-Boot so it has nothing to do with jWT or React. You will get the same error if you open your spring-Boot page without JavaScript.

Comment: Hi @jcubic, you're very right, thanks for pointing that out. I'll try to figure out how to separate them! And could you kindly tell me, if you will, where the SpringBoot problem is?

Comment: I have no idea what the problem may be, I check reactjs tag questions and this is not related to React.

Comment: @jcubic I am so grateful for your kind reply. I was checking the Java Code and realized so much more fundamental SpringBoot Component issues from my codes. I am too new to React so had no idea if there were anything wrong with the React. Thank you so much for your assurance! :) Thanks again so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who saw this problem, I found the answer now. It's because I am returning response, but cookie itself is already a HTTP response. So one possible solution is:

```
@PostMapping("/login")
    public void login(@RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String jwt = // generate jwt here

        // Set the JWT as a cookie
        Cookie jwtCookie = new Cookie("jwt", jwt);
        response.addCookie(jwtCookie);

        // Don't try to return any JSON
```